# Exim: temporarily rejected connection in "connect" ACL

Tags: log-files, access-control-list, exim

2 Weeks ago, I randomly received the message "temporarily rejected connection in "connect" ACL" in the Exim mainlog.  I tried clearing the Exim ratelimit files, restarting everything, but nothing fixed it.  Then randomly, it came back up and all mail servers accepted mail, showing "completed"

Now today it's happening again; everything on google shows info for "Temporarily rejected connection in “connect” ACL: ratelimit database not available", but this is not my issue.  My error is exactly:

2011-06-15 14:50:21 H=fujifilm-121.fujifilm.tracker.postdirect.com [206.165.242.121] temporarily rejected connection in "connect" ACL
  2011-06-15 14:50:21 H=mail3094.midwayusa.mkt3690.com [208.95.133.86] temporarily rejected connection in "connect" ACL
  2011-06-15 14:50:21 H=bay0-omc1-s22.bay0.hotmail.com [65.54.190.33] temporarily rejected   connection in "connect" ACL
  2011-06-15 14:50:21 H=cpe-72-226-109-27.nycap.res.rr.com [72.226.109.27] temporarily rejected connection in "connect" ACL

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: You won't get much useful help without telling the world what your `acl_smtp_connect` actually is.

Comment: please rewrite your comment as the answer to your question below and accept it (once you are allowed to) so that other people with your problem will see it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this out. The problem was my own "trusted_mail_hosts" list which is a listing of gmail.com, hotmail.com, *.hotmail.com, etc. It seems sbcglobal.com was unable to be resolved (something on their end), which caused my issue. When running exim in debug mode from itself, it kept complaining about SBCGlobal.com in the list; I modified my list, removed sbcglobal.com and *.sbcglobal.com and the thing worked just fine. Exim will try to resolve the hosts in any list in the "connect" acl; if it cannot the whole thing collapses. Anyways, hope this helps someone with a similar problem.